# Easeljs: When loading image on to easeljs bitmap class, does it use original image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, easeljs

I am using Easeljs on my website. I tried to load the image on a bitmap object from CreateJS.bitmap. Since i am not using the full size image, if i scaled the bitmap, will it downsample the original image accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no down-sampling of the actual image, but the pixels that are laid down on the Canvas  would be effectively down-sampled.

To actually down-sample the source image, you could scale an EaselJS Bitmap, then retrieve the canvas as an image using `stage.toDataUrl()`. This returns an image that could be used elsewhere.